# Wave-particle duality

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electrons

Can I get an answer stating some analogies on how electrons behave like a wave, and what does it even mean for an electron to behave like a wave? 
Also, if going around the nucleus, is electron a real physical wave or a probability distribution wave? And when in motion otherwise, (like an electron shot towards something) does it travel like a wave? I mean like up and down and up down that sort? Or is this wave different in some kind?

I'm really having a very hard time understanding this stuff, please help

PS- can you suggest a book which explains me this in kinda fun and intuitive way rather than mathematical balderdash?

Comment: That mathematical balderdash is what called science...

Comment: Fun and intuitive only gets you a certain part of the way. Would you like a pilot, a surgeon or nuclear engineer learn their craft in a "kinda fun and intuitive way"? There is a benefit to a quantitative treatment.

Comment: @KarstenTheis But that builds a base, at least.

Comment: @user231094 Sometimes it builds a strong base and sometimes it builds something that you have to remove again before you can continue (like a misconception). But I guess that's why you are asking for a recommendation.

Comment: One major complication of intuition is there is no guarantee that your intuition has anything to do with my intuition. If I tell you to think of the electron as a blue, fuzzy sphere with orange sparks flying off of it, you'd think I'm crazy. Well, I just might be, but it kind of works (well, the sparks aren't orange, but you get the picture).

Answer (score 3):

Electrons and photons behave similarly regarding diffraction and interference.

- First consider a *wave* going through a single slit, as the amplitude of the waveform and its diffracted component interfere, creating a high central peak and weaker side-lobes. This follows [Fraunhofer's formula](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/sinslit.html), which applies to sinusoidal *waves*.
- When a photon or an electron beam passes through a [double-slit](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/15/3/033018), it forms an interference pattern combined with the diffraction pattern, as the peaks and troughs of the waves sum or cancel.

[image: Single and Double Slit Experiments (635 nm photons)]

- In both the case of the electron and photon, *detection* relies on the behavior of a *particle*, as if all its mass/energy is at a point. A single electron can be observed as a scintillation in a phosphor (e.g. cathode ray tube, CRT). A single photon has the energy to activate one particle of a silver halide emulsion.
- If the flux of electrons (or photons) is reduced so that only a single "particle" is going through a double slit at a time, the double-slit interference pattern is not disturbed at all! This is one of the mind-boggling challenges of physics -- the electron or photon clearly is detected at only a single point, i.e. as a *particle*, yet behaves as a *wave* by interfering with itself. Which slit did the single particle go though? *Both at once and the same time!*

See this [NYU lecture slide](https://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/adv.chem/lectures/lecture_5/node1.html) on wave-particle duality. This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCmtegdqOOA) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=DfPeprQ7oGc) might help, too.